# Fix para nth-child(n)

Tags: css, css3

Existe algum fix para o `:nth-child(n)` do CSS3? para rodar no IE8?
Pois, tenho um arquivo em CSS que usei esse seletor, ele não roda apenas no IE8

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Via CSS, o método que usava quando dava suporte a Internet Explorer 7 e 8 era fazendo uso do selector de irmãos adjacentes:

[Adjacent sibling selectors `+`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors) <sup>(Inglês)</sup>

```
/* equivalente ao li:nth-child(1) */
ul li:first-child a {
    color:red;
}

/* equivalente ao li:nth-child(2) */
ul li:first-child + li a {
    color:blue;
}

/* equivalente ao li:nth-child(3) */
ul li:first-child + li + li a {
    color:green;
}​

/* equivalente ao li:nth-child(4) */
ul li:first-child + li + li + li a {
    color:yellow;
}​

/* ... e por ai a fora ... */
```

---

```css
/* equivalente ao li:nth-child(1) */
ul li:first-child a {
    color:red;
}

/* equivalente ao li:nth-child(2) */
ul li:first-child + li a {
    color:blue;
}

/* equivalente ao li:nth-child(3) */
ul li:first-child + li + li a {
    color:green;
}

/* equivalente ao li:nth-child(4) */
ul li:first-child + li + li + li a {
    color:yellow;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Vermelho</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Azul</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Verde</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Amarelo</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Exemplo também no [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zuul/jLc8LL3d/).